# How to compare more than 3 objects?

Tags: java

I have an array that consist of 3 or more Person objects and I'm figuring out how to compare each of them to find the "best" youngest and tallest person.

```
public class Person {

    private int age;
    private int height;

    public int Person( int age, int height ) {
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public int getHeight() { return height; }
}
```

In my implementation, I add the Person objects in an array like so:

```
Array<Person> persons = new Array<Person>();
persons.add( new Person(28, 150) );
persons.add( new Person(38, 155) );
persons.add( new Person(18, 160) );
```

Given the array, how do I compare the persons object from an iterations?

```
for( int i=0; i<persons.size; i++ ) {
    Person person = persons.get(i);

    // compare age and height?
}
```

Comment: I suspect you're looking for how to sort an array?

Comment: implement the `comparable` or `comparator` interface and call `sort()` based on your implementation, you will get the person as first in the sorted array / list.

Comment: Not an Answer, public int Person( int age, int height ) method there is no return statement,or write it as constructor

Answer (score 1):

You could sort, but I suspect you just want this.

```
Person youngest = null;
Person tallest = null;
int lowest_age = 0;
int tallest_height = 0;

for( int i=0; i<persons.size; i++ )
{
    Person person = persons.get(i);
    int age = person.getAge();
    int height = person.getHeight();

    if ((age < lowest_age || (youngest == null))
    {
       lowest_age = age;
       youngest = person;
    }

    if ((height > tallest_height || (tallest == null))
    {
       tallest_height = height;
       tallest = person;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tirath - good catch. My mind was on C++.  Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Try using Comparable interface, something like this :

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.CompareToBuilder;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    private int age;
    private int height;

    public int Person( int age, int height ) {
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public int getHeight() { return height; }

    public int compareTo(Person other) { 
        return new CompareToBuilder().append(age, other.age).append(height, other.height).toComparison(); 
    }
}
```

Then, here how you use it :

```
persons.sort();
```

Note : If you want to sort descending, just switch the internal property and the property of other object, something like this :

```
public int compareTo(Person other) { 
    return new CompareToBuilder().append(age, other.age).append(other.height, height).toComparison();
}
```

Comment: I think this is the way I should do it. I just managed to installed apache.commons.lang and working nicely now. Thank you and everyone so much! Appreciate all you guys help.

Comment: You're welcome. Please choose my answer if you think it is the best answer by click the tick icon beside my answer. Have a nice day :-)